# Gtk+ 3 tooltips not showing up on button

Tags: python-2.7, button, tooltip, pygtk, gtk3

Tooltips aren't showing up on my buttons.  I should probably clear this up:  they show up on my regular buttons, but any buttons that are added to my overlay object don't show the tooltips.

```
# Overlay
self.overlay = Gtk.Overlay()
self.overlay.show()

# Image
self.image_pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file("pics/sgcity.png")
self.image_pixbuf = self.image_pixbuf.scale_simple(1200, 720, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.BILINEAR)
self.image = Gtk.Image()
self.image.set_from_pixbuf(self.image_pixbuf)
self.overlay.add(self.image)
self.image.show()

# Printer Buttons
for i in range(len(self.printbuttons)):
    self.printbuttons[i].destroy()
    self.printbuttons = []
    self.button_attribs = []
    self.logic.create_printer_button_attributes()
    self.button_attribs = self.logic.get_printer_button_attributes()
for i in range(len(printer_store)):
    self.printbuttons.append(Gtk.Button(None))
    self.printerimg = Gtk.Image()
    self.printerimg.set_from_file("pics/printer.png")
    self.printbuttons[i].set_image(self.printerimg)
    self.overlay.add_overlay(self.printbuttons[i])
    self.printbuttons[i].set_name('printbuttons')
    self.printbuttons[i].set_opacity(0.8)
    self.printbuttons[i].set_tooltip_text(printer_store[i][0])
    self.printbuttons[i].show()
for i in range(len(self.printbuttons)):
    self.printbuttons[i].connect("enter", self.on_printer_image_entered)
    self.printbuttons[i].connect("leave", self.on_printer_image_left)
    self.printbuttons[i].connect("clicked", self.on_printer_button_clicked, printer_store[i])

# Quit Button
    self.quit_button = Gtk.Button("Quit")
    self.quit_button.show()
    self.quit_button.set_tooltip_text("GET OUTTA HERE!!!")

def register_handlers(self):
    self.department_combo.connect("changed", self.on_department_combo_changed)
    self.building_combo.connect("changed", self.on_building_combo_changed)
    self.floor_combo.connect("changed", self.on_floor_combo_changed)
    self.printer_combo.connect("changed", self.on_printer_combo_changed)
    self.update_button.connect('clicked', self.update_floor_plan)
    self.install_button.connect('clicked', self.on_install_button_clicked)
    self.uninstall_button.connect('clicked', self.on_uninstall_button_clicked)
    self.help_button.connect('clicked', self.on_help_button_clicked)
    self.quit_button.connect('clicked', self.destroy_handler)
    self.main_window.connect('delete-event', self.delete_event_handler)
    self.main_window.connect('destroy', self.destroy_handler)
    return

def run(self):
    Gtk.main()


# This method is called by the 'X' button on the window,
# or as a result of Gtk.main_quit()
def delete_event_handler(self, widget, event, data=None):
    # return False to indicate that we agree with the window
    # being deleted.
    self.helpWindow.destroy_handler()
    return False

# This method is called by the 'quit' button
def destroy_handler(self, widget, data=None):
    self.helpWindow.destroy_handler()
    Gtk.main_quit()
    return

def get_child_position(self, overlay, widget, allocation):
    for i in range(len(self.printbuttons)):
        if widget == self.printbuttons[i]:
            allocation.x = self.button_attribs[i][0]
            allocation.y = self.button_attribs[i][1]
            allocation.height = self.button_attribs[i][2]
            allocation.width = self.button_attribs[i][3]
    print "changed"
    return True

def on_printer_image_entered(self, button, tip):
    button.set_opacity(1)
    button.set_tooltip_text(tip)
    return
def on_printer_image_left(self, button):
    button.set_opacity(0.8)
    return
def on_printer_button_clicked(self, button, printer):
    for i in range(len(self.printer_combo.get_model())):
        if printer[0] == self.printer_combo.get_model()[i][0]:
            active_printer = i
            self.printer_combo.set_active(active_printer)
    print printer[0]
    return
```

Obviously this isn't my whole program, but it has all the important elements.  The quit button comes up with a tool tip, but the print buttons do not.  As I said, I suspect its because they're part of the overlay, but I really do not know.  If anyone has any insight, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note:  if I set the tool tip on the Overlay, it shows up regardless of whether I'm on the button or not.

Comment: It would be much easier (for us) if you could add minimal code which makes the code actually work, so we can test it. Anyway, I suspect that the connections to the `leave` and `enter` events are what is causing your problem - I suspect they disable the tooltips.

Comment: Ok, edited the post adding more code...  hopefully this helps more?  I had the same thought as you, regarding the enter/leave, so I tested it on a button not in the overlay, and it worked fine...

Comment: Did this program really run in Gtk3? You have eg. `print printer[0]` which is deprecated in Gtk3. (Also `print "changed"`). Also, you use `self` at the left margin. `Self` normally refers to the instance of a class - is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, they're all instances of my main window class.  sorry, I forgot to remove the print statements.  all printer[0] is just text in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat guessing here, but I think this is a (yet another) CSS problem.
If you run this demo code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  untitled.py
#  
#  Copyright 2016 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  


from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)

        overlay = Gtk.Overlay()

        (yet another) textview = Gtk.TextView()
        textview.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.WORD_CHAR)
        textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
        textbuffer.set_text("Welcome to the PyGObject Tutorial\n\nThis guide aims to provide an introduction to using Python and GTK+.\n\nIt includes many sample code files and exercises for building your knowledge of the language.", -1)
        overlay.add(textview)

        button = Gtk.Button(label="Overlayed Button")
        button.set_property("tooltip-text", "Test tooltip")
        #button.connect("enter-notify-event", self.on_overlay_btn_entered)
        button.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        button.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        overlay.add_overlay(button)


        self.add(overlay)
        overlay.show_all()
        self.show_all()

    def on_overlay_btn_entered(self, btn, event):
        print("Overlay button entered")
        return True


    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0
```

Then it seems, at first sight, that the tooltip doesn't work. But
carefully position the cursor on the (1px wide) border of the box, and the tooltip *does* appear. With the initial popup delay of the tooltip, you've probably just never seen it.

I suspect that no CSS is defined for the color/background of the overlaid tooltip.

Here's a screenshot for the tooltip that appeared:

[image: Tooltip image]

Comment: Yep, thats the problem...  why does it just apply the tool tip to the border?...  And how could I go about fixing that?

Comment: When I have a moment, I'll try and look into this. I'm no expert though. I've seen a message where Gtk.Overlay was announced, and it seemed quite recent. To be sure, I've submitted a bug report to Gtk (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=768156)

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping.  I really appreciate it.  Its for my senior project/my workplace and it'd be really helpful if I could get these working properly.  But now that I have this info, I have somewhere to start and try figuring this thing out.  If you get any word on the bug ticket, let me know.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. You can subscribe to the bug so if any news arrives you'll be on the mailing list. It will also add some weight for those who have to solve it ;-)

Comment: Oh hey, I forgot to mention.  I don't think its a css issue, because my buttons already have the border color and width increased (in css), but the tool tip only shows up on a 1px border, rather than the css defined border.  Just thought I would throw that out there.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, and I passed it on the bug tracker!